# Why is the output printed twice with write() and not with print() in IPC using pipe?

Tags: c, linux, ipc

My question is simple and straight forward.Here i am trying to send a data at the one end of pipe and trying to read from the other end.I am trying to learn IPC mechanism and i got stuck while doing this simple program.if i am using print()[1] in the  Parent process then ,

```
o/p is 

In the child process
IN the parent process and its sleeping
SUBI IS IN LOVE WITH PUTHALATH
```

But if i am using write()[2 commented in the below program] in the parent process

```
 o/p is 

 In the child process
 IN the parent process and its sleeping
 SUBI IS IN LOVE WITH PUTHALATHIN the parent process and its sleeping
```

Why is the line "IN the parent process and its sleeping" got printed twice?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(){

   int fd[2];
   pipe(fd);

  if(!fork()){
    printf("In the child process\n");
    close(1);
    dup(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    write(1,"SUBI IS IN LOVE WITH PUTHALATH", 200);

   } else {
      sleep(1);
      printf("IN the parent process and its sleeping \n");
      char* stream;
      close(fd[1]);
       read(fd[0],stream,200);
       printf("%s",stream);------>(1)
      // write(1,stream,200);---->(2)
    }
     return 0;
    }
```

Any help pls because i am stuck here.

Comment: Note: you're not allocating memory to `stream`. Thus the `read` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The `stream` name is confusing. Call it `buf` and declare it `char buf[256];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the child, you

```
write(1,"SUBI IS IN LOVE WITH PUTHALATH", 200);
```

write 200 bytes to  the pipe, starting from where the string literal begins.

When you

```
write(1,stream,200);
```

in the parent (after having allocated memory to `stream`), you write the 200 bytes written to the pipe by the child, while the `printf` stops at the 0 byte terminating the string literal `"SUBI IS IN LOVE WITH PUTHALATH"`.

So whatever bytes follow that string literal in memory get printed out too. The string literal `"IN the parent process and its sleeping \n"` is apparently located within that memory section.

Comment: one thing that i didnt understand is In the child i am writing 200 bytes starting from the beginning of the string.But the actual length of the string is only 30bytes.so what about the remaining bytes written to the pipe.will it write null for the rest of 200-30 = 170 bytes?

Comment: You told it to write 200 bytes, and you gave it an address where to look for the bytes (remember, all that `write` sees of "SUBI ..." is the address of the first byte; `write` doesn't know it's a string, so it has no reason to stop when it reaches the 0-terminator; it goes on until it has written the specified 200 bytes, or is stopped due to an access violation [if you tell it to write more than the size of the buffer, it happily oversteps]). After the 31 bytes (including the 0-terminator) of the string literal, it goes on to write whatever is stored after it.

Comment: > OK i got it.since i used like this write(1,stream,strlen(stream))-->(2) in the parent process,it printed only the strings "SUBI IS IN LOVE WITH PUTHALATH".Because strlen() stops at the first null character.Thats why while printing in the parent process using write() instead of print(),it printed only those 30 bytes not the entire 200 bytes.am i right Dani?

Comment: Yes, if you use `strlen(stream)` as the size parameter to `write`, you tell it to write only up to the first 0 byte. Now, if the `write` in the child only writes `strlen("SUBI ....")` bytes, you need to 0-initialise the buffer the parent `read`s into, or you don't know where the first 0 byte will be, and then `strlen(stream)` can cause undefined behaviour and may crash.

Answer (score 0):

> BUGS

```
   It is not advisable to mix calls to output functions from the stdio library
   with low-level calls to write(2) for the file descriptor associated with
   the same output stream; the results will be undefined and very probably not
   what you want.
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html

And as others pointed out, you didn't allocate memory for your stream..

Answer (score 0):

When I tried compiling this, gcc says:

```
22:12: warning: ‘stream’ may be used uninitialized in this function
[-Wuninitialized]
```

Which is a major indication!

Change `char *stream` to `char stream[200];` and it works as expected. But if you call that `write` at the end, you'll write well beyond the string with whatever happens to be in memory after it, and as it's not initialised to 0, it'll probably be random rubbish. You can correct that with this:

```
write(1, stream, strlen(stream)); //correct length, not all 200 bytes
```

Really, though, you should not be writing 200 bytes in the parent, because you're writing from memory you haven't allocated. The number should be equal to the length of the string (plus one for `\0`).