# Why do I get double output from pipe?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to read from the pipe once and print out the results, but I get a double output.

I thought the read and write sizes were incorrect ([Why is the output printed twice with write() and not with print() in IPC using pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369785/why-is-the-output-printed-twice-with-write-and-not-with-print-in-ipc-using-p)), but I printed out the size in the child before the write and then tried inputted the same size to the read function and I still get a double output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct
{
    int PID;
    char *filename;
    int wordCount;
    int lineCount;
    int byteCount;

} filestr;

int pipe(int pd[2]);
void mywc(FILE *fp, char *name, filestr *fileA);
int isParam(char* fileName);
int getParam(int argCount, char **args);
void error_exit(char *s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pd[2], status, pid, param, 
    wordT=0, lineT=0, byteT=0;
    filestr fileAtr;


    //param = getParam(argc, argv);
    //printf("PARAM: %d\n", param);

    if(pipe(pd) == -1)
        error_exit("pipe() failed");

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            FILE *file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if(file != 0){
                mywc(file, argv[i], &fileAtr);

                wait(NULL);
                close(pd[0]);

                printf("SIZE: %d\n", sizeof(fileAtr));
                if(write(pd[1], &fileAtr, sizeof(fileAtr)) == -1)
                    error_exit("write() failed");   
            }




            exit(0);
        }
    }

    int sum;
    for(int j = 0; j < argc; ++j)
    {
        close(pd[1]);

        if(read(pd[0], &fileAtr, (32*sizeof(int))) == -1)
            error_exit("read() failed");
        printf("PID : %d\n", fileAtr.PID);
        printf("File Name : %s\n", fileAtr.filename);
        printf("Words : %d\n", fileAtr.wordCount);
        printf("Lines : %d\n", fileAtr.lineCount);
        printf("Bytes : %d\n\n", fileAtr.byteCount);    

        wordT += fileAtr.wordCount;
        lineT += fileAtr.lineCount;
        byteT += fileAtr.byteCount;
    }
    printf("Grand Total: word: %d line: %d byte: %d\n", wordT, lineT, byteT);

}

void mywc(FILE *fp, char *name, filestr *fileA)
{
    int c, lineCount=0, wordCount=0, byteCount=0;

    while( (c = getc(fp)) != EOF )
    {

        if( c == ' ' )
        {
            wordCount++;
            byteCount++;
        }
        else if ( c == '\n')
        {
            wordCount++;
            byteCount++;
            lineCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            byteCount++;
        }
    }

    fileA->PID = getpid();
    fileA->filename = name;
    fileA->wordCount = wordCount;
    fileA->lineCount = lineCount;
    fileA->byteCount = byteCount;
}

int getParam(int argCount, char **args)
{
    int param;
    for(int i = 0; i < argCount; i++)
    {
        if((strcmp(args[i], "-lwc") == 0) || (strcmp(args[i], "-lcw") == 0) || (strcmp(args[i], "-wlc") == 0) 
            || (strcmp(args[i], "-wcl") == 0) || (strcmp(args[i], "-cwl") == 0) || (strcmp(args[i], "-clw") == 0))
            param = 3;
        else if((strcmp(args[i], "-w") == 0))
            param = 0;
        else if((strcmp(args[i], "-l") == 0))
            param = 1;
        else if((strcmp(args[i], "-c") == 0))
            param = 2;
    }
    return param;
}

void error_exit(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);
}
```

My Ouput:

```
SIZE: 32
PID : 14896
File Name : test
Words : 4
Lines : 4
Bytes : 26

PID : 14896
File Name : test
Words : 4
Lines : 4
Bytes : 26

Grand Total: word: 8 line: 8 byte: 52
```

EDIT: Added full code

Comment: You need to produce a reproducible example, including all of your `#include`s and the definition of `mywc`.

Comment: Where are `wordT`, `lineT`, and `byteT` defined? And what's a `filestr`?

Comment: Note that your `j` loop runs one more times than the `i` loop.

Comment: Note that `read` will return `0` at EOF, not `-1`.

Comment: @dxiv I'm in disbelief... that was the problem. thank you.

Comment: How do I delete this question?

Comment: @dshin You don't. You never, ever delete a question just because you figured out the answer.

Comment: @dshin Glad it helped. That was only *one* problem, though, if you read the other comments. P.S. There would be no SO if everyone deleted their solved questions. Don't.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm fine with leaving it but the fact that it was a for-loop error I thought it might've been useless to other people.  If it helps others then I am fine leaving it.

Answer (score 2):

The loop that prints your output

```
for(int j = 0; j < argc; ++j)
{
    ...
}
```

Goes from `j = 0` instead of `j = 1`. `argc` is 2. So it prints the output twice.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of two problems: First, `for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)` will run `argc - 1` times, but `for(int j = 0; j < argc; ++j)` will run `argc` times. Second, `if(read(pd[0], &fileAtr, (32*sizeof(int))) == -1)` only handles one thing that `read` can do. In addition to failing with `-1`, it can also return `0` when it gets to EOF, or return some bytes, but fewer than you asked for (called a partial read). In your case, the EOF is happening, but your code doesn't notice, so it just happily goes along with the data that happened to already be there (in this case, a duplicate of the final result).